# JavaScript: get value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, getelementbyid, html-select

I have 3 HTML combo/drop down boxes. All of them have a distinct name and id.
On a particular event I want to get the value of all three of them.
Can any one give me a code snippet for that?

Comment: Do you know about "Accept" button in every answer you get on your question?

Comment: plz tell me how to accpt the answer.I can see only commet button.
Many people have asked me to accpet the answe.But i dont know how to accpet.Where is the option

Comment: In every answer on your question, just below the number of votes, there is a "v" like sign. Choose the answer you most like and press this "v" sign.

Comment: It's actually a checkmark, not a V :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using jQuery:

```
$("#dropdownID").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this not using jQuery:

```
function getSelectValues() {
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var select = document.getElementById(arguments[i]);
        if (select) {
            values[i] = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        } else {
            values[i] = null;
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

This function returns an array of values that correspond to the `id`s you pass into the function, as follows:

```
var selectValues = getSelectValues('id1', 'id2', 'id3');
```

If a `<select>` with one of your specified `id`s does not exist the array contains `null` for the value for that position.

There are a couple of other ways to do this, you could pass the function an array of `id` values: `getSelectValues([ 'id1', 'id2', 'id3' ])`, in which case the function would be changed:

```
function getSelectValues(ids) {
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    // ...
```

You could also pass the function a map of `id`s and populate the values:

```
var myMap = { 'id1': null, 'id2': null, 'id3': null };
getSelectValues(myMap);
// myMap['id1'] contains the value for id1, etc
```

This would change the function to be:

```
function getSelectValues(map) {
    for (var id in map) {
        var select = document.getElementById(id);
        if (select) {
            map[id] = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        } else {
            map[id] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to set them up next to each other in your HTML and then iterate through them using jQuery's built-in each() method.  You'd set up your elements like this:

```
<div id="dropdownBoxes">
<select id="firstElement">
    <option>cool</option>
    <option>neat</option>
</select>
<select id="secondElement">
    <option>fun</option>
    <option>awesome</option>
</select>
<select id="thirdElement">
    <option>great</option>
    <option>synonym</option>
</select>
</div>

<input type="button" id="theTrigger">Push me!</input>
```

Then, in your script:

```
var dropdownValues;

$("#theTrigger").click(function(){    
dropdownValues.length=0;
$("#dropdownBoxes select").each(function(){
    dropdownValues.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework like jQuery mentioned above or just do it the old school way. `document.getElementById('dropdownId').value` .